# How do I see Db2 recovery and administrative event history from the db2 on cloud "console"

Tags: list, console, db2, history

I've seen the documentation here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ca/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001991.html

but I can't run it from the "generate SQL" area of the console? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY` administrative view as mentioned in the link you gave

Comment: Gave that a try yesterday, but it doesn't work. See this screenshot for what it looks like: https://imgur.com/WVMdxn2

Comment: It is a `VIEW` so you need to `SELECT` from it. I.e try  `SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY`

Comment: Thanks! I now get this error "The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.  Authorization ID: "RHW03364".  Operation: "SELECT". Object: "SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY".. SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, DRIVER=4.26.14"

What authorization do I need? I am, after all, the one that created the db instance...

Comment: The manual will tell you what authorization as needed. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022351.html If this is a shared instance (e.g. the free Db2 on Cloud Lite plan) you won't be able to have the required authority to see this data as it is not schema specific

Comment: BTW what are you hoping to get from this view?  Your original question just asked for "history",  but that is not very clear about what kind of history you were hoping to see

Comment: ah, okay thanks. Yeah this is just on the free DB2 Lite Tier. I was hoping to be able to see a history of what commands were ran (I.e. what was inserted, selected, etc.)

Comment: That view does not provide such a history.  Also the free tier does not provide a history of SQL. You would need a paid tier and I think also Data Server Manager to get a statement history https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-adv_admin_dsm

Comment: Okay, understood. Thanks so much for your help!